# XSLT - suitable for the task?

Tags: xml, xslt, parallel-processing, transformation, text-processing

I have a requirement of transforming a *huge* XML document into multiple HTML documents.
The XML is as follows:

```
<society>
  <party_members>
    <member id="1" first_name="" last_name="O'Brien">
      <ministry_id>1</ministry_id>
      <ministry_id>3</ministry_id>
    </member>
    <member id="2" first_name="Julia" last_name="">
      <ministry_id>2</ministry_id>
    </member>
    <member id="3" first_name="Winston" last_name="Smith">
      <ministry_id>1</ministry_id>
    </member>
  </party_members>
  <ministries>
    <ministry>
      <id>1</id>
      <short_title>Minitrue</short_title>
      <long_title>Ministry of truth</long_title>
      <concerns>News, entertainment,education and arts </concerns>      
    </ministry>
    <ministry>
      <id>2</id>
      <short_title>Minipax</short_title>
      <long_title>Ministry of Peace</long_title>
      <concerns>War</concerns>
    </ministry>
    <ministry>
      <id>3</id>
      <short_title>Minilove</short_title>
      <long_title>Ministry of Love</long_title>
      <concerns>Dissidents</concerns>      
    </ministry>
  </ministries>
</society>
```

Where potential number of party members can be quite large - millions, and number of ministries is small, around 300-400. For each of the party member there should be an output HTML with following content:

```
<html>  
  <body>
    <h2>Party member: Winston Smith</h2>
    <h3>Works in:</h3>
    <div class="ministry">
      <h4>Ministry of truth</h4> - Minitrue
      <h5>Ministry of truth <i>concerns</i> itself with <i>News, entertainment,education and arts</i></h5>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The number of output documents should == number of party members.

I'm now struggling with XSLT, but can't get it to work.

Please help me decide if XSLT is a good tool for this job, if it is, hint me as if how to implement it, what XSLT constructs should be used, etc.

Of course I could simply write mini transformation in a procedural language, but I'm looking for a '*apply transformation template*' approach, rather than procedural parsing and modification to be able to hand the template to other users for further modifications (CSS, formatting etc).

I'm using ruby + nokogiri(which is a set of bindings to libxslt), but it is possible to use any language.

If XSTL is a bad fit for this task, what other instruments can be used here, provided I must transform ~1M of users in several minutes with small memory consumption?

Additional benefit would be to be able to parallelize the processing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this result (producing several html files) you definitely need XSLT 2.0. I suggest the usage of Saxon for that.

Here you have a sample XSL which produces what you need (creates a single html file for each member, all inside a "html" folder in your sytem's root, and gives back a report of what it created). You'll probably need to tweek it a little bit to fit your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="html"/>
    <xsl:variable name="target-dir" select="'/html'"/>
    <xsl:key name="ministries" match="/society/ministries/ministry" use="id"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </Output>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="member">
        <Html path="{concat($target-dir,'/',@id,'.html')}">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat($target-dir,'/',@id,'.html')}">
                <html>
                  <body>
                    <h2><xsl:value-of select="concat('Party member: ',@first_name,' ',@last_name)"/></h2>
                    <h3>Works in:</h3>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ministry_id"/>
                  </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </Html>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="ministry_id">
    <xsl:variable name="ministry" select="key('ministries',.)"/>
    <div class="ministry">
        <h4><xsl:value-of select="$ministry/long_title"/></h4> - <xsl:value-of select="$ministry/short_title"/>
        <h5><xsl:value-of select="$ministry/long_title"/> <i>concerns</i> itself with <i><xsl:value-of select="$ministry/concerns"/></i></h5>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here you have a sample output:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Party member:  O'Brien</h2>
      <h3>Works in:</h3>
      <div class="ministry">
         <h4>Ministry of truth</h4> - Minitrue
         <h5>Ministry of truth<i>concerns</i> itself with <i>News, entertainment,education and arts </i></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="ministry">
         <h4>Ministry of Love</h4> - Minilove
         <h5>Ministry of Love<i>concerns</i> itself with <i>Dissidents</i></h5>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Regarding performance, several millions is a big amount of data. I guess that xsl will be enough for it, but I'm afraid you'll need to give it a try before knowing for sure.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank Carles, I'll try your solution and write an update what worked and how with simple benchmarks.

Comment: Hi Valentin, did you manage to give this option a try? I'm curious about the benchmarking results

Comment: Hi Carles, I've implemented only a simple 'proof-of-concept' template and saxon version is ~ 4 times faster than libxml, now I'm working on a full template, which is thousands lines long, as soon as it's ready, I'll update the question.

Comment: After all testing it all works fine and quite fast, produces 300MBs of html in 12 seconds.4-5 times faster than LibXSLT version. How can I profile the saxon XSLT?

Answer (score 3):

Well with pure XSLT 1.0 you can't create multiple result documents with a single transformation which you seem to want to do. For that you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML with the XSLT 2.0 instruction `[xsl:result-document][1]` or you need to use an XSLT 1.0 processor like xsltproc/libxslt which implements http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html. If you can use one of them then XSLT is well suited for your task.

[edit]
With libxslt respectively xsltproc the following stylesheet code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="ministry-by-id" match="ministry" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="society/party_members/member" mode="doc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="member" mode="doc">
  <exsl:document href="member{@id}.xml">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Party member: <xsl:value-of select="concat(@first_name, ' ', @last_name)"/></h2>
        <h3>Works in</h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ministry-by-id', ministry_id)"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </exsl:document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ministry">
  <div class="ministry">
    <h4><xsl:value-of select="long_title"/></h4>
    <h5><xsl:value-of select="long_title"/> <i>concerns</i> itself with <i><xsl:value-of select="concerns"/></i></h5>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

shows how to use `exsl:document` to output several result documents with one transformation. It also uses a key to improve performance. Let us know whether that code works for your huge input data.

Comment: `libxslt` should be able to do the job of creating multiple result documents, of course with any XSLT task an input document that large with consume lots of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the transformation you need using XSLT should be simple, but I don't think it is the right technology to process such a big XML in one go: it will load the entire data in memory and work from there, not a nice thing for such a big data set.

If each HTML document corresponds to a small contiguous section of the overall document, I'd suggest to split the big XML file using a program (using an XML parser that does not load the entire document in memory), and then convert each piece using an XSLT.

If each HTML document contains data coming from different parts of the files and/or aggregates (e.g. the total number of members matching some criteria) I'd suggest to parse the XML and load its data in a SQL database, and then generate the HTML files reading from this database.

Answer (score 1):

The bulk of the work definitely can be done in XSLT 1.0, although as Martin says, you can only produce one document, containing all the HTML exerpts. From this, you can use an XPath technology to select each of the html nodes and return the OuterXml of each node, for you to write away to file / database etc.

It might not however be feasible to process all party members at once due to memory constraints.

Since there is no dependency on party members to other members (only to ministries), I would recommend that you process the party members a 1000 or so at a time, with all ministries present in the XML document. You can also split the ministries to a separate xml file and use `xsl:document` to load the ministries during processing of each of your party members xml files.

**Edit** : [xsl:document reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document), and usage example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832545/how-to-merge-two-xml-file-using-xslt1-0)

**The following XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0"
                >

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/society">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="party_members/member" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="member">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>
                    Party member: <xsl:value-of select="@first_name"/><xsl:text xml:space="preserve"> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@last_name"/>
                </h2>
                <h3>Works in:</h3>
                <div class="ministry">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ministry_id">
                        <xsl:variable name="ministryId" select="./text()" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/society/ministries/ministry[id=$ministryId]" mode="partymember"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ministry" mode="partymember">
        <h4>
            <xsl:value-of select="long_title"/>
        </h4> -     <xsl:value-of select="short_title"/>
        <h5>
            <xsl:value-of select="long_title"/><i>concerns</i> itself with <i>
                <xsl:value-of select="concerns"/>
            </i>
        </h5>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following output (after pretty printing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>
                Party member:  O'Brien
            </h2>
            <h3>Works in:</h3>
            <div class="ministry">
                <h4>Ministry of truth</h4> -        Minitrue<h5>
                    Ministry of truth<i>concerns</i> itself with <i>News, entertainment,education and arts </i>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>
                Party member: Julia
            </h2>
            <h3>Works in:</h3>
            <div class="ministry">
                <h4>Ministry of Peace</h4> -        Minipax<h5>
                    Ministry of Peace<i>concerns</i> itself with <i>War</i>
                </h5><h4>Ministry of Love</h4> -        Minilove<h5>
                    Ministry of Love<i>concerns</i> itself with <i>Dissidents</i>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>
                Party member: Winston Smith
            </h2>
            <h3>Works in:</h3>
            <div class="ministry">
                <h4>Ministry of truth</h4> -        Minitrue<h5>
                    Ministry of truth<i>concerns</i> itself with <i>News, entertainment,education and arts </i>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you @nonnb, could you please share a link for the external linking documentation?

Comment: @ValentinVasilyev - Re : Why was Julia in 2 ministries - the original xml didn't have a ministry id=3 (id=2 was duplicated, hence Julia had 2 ministries)

Answer (score 1):

How big is "huge"? If there are a million members, my guess for the size of Saxon's TinyTree would be about 100Mb, which is certainly feasible to do in memory. But you're probably dangerously close to the point where a main memory transformation isn't possible, and you then have to consider a streaming transformation.

Fortunately this doesn't make using XSLT impossible, though it does restrict your range of possible XSLT processors.

Saxon-EE supports streaming transformation based on the draft XSLT 3.0 specifications, however, you often have to write the code in a slightly different way. In this example, to use streaming you will first need to split the "ministries" data into a separate file - you can do the split as a streaming transformation with two result documents. Then in the main transformation, you can do streamed processing of the "members" data, together with in-memory processing of the "ministries" data, using keys as suggested by Carles Sala.

Streaming XSLT is bleeding-edge technology, so we're always very willing to help users who decide to try it out.